# General text wrap program in C

Tags: c, formatting, word-wrap, ansi-escape

I'm trying to make a general text wrap in C. Basically it should handle the text in the following way:

- A maximum line length is determined
- It must always wrap the text in the spaces, when it is dealing with words smaller than the maximum line length
- For big words, it should break the word in two when it reaches the length limit
- It also handles ANSI characters to account for the "invisible" characters.

What I came up with until now is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_PRINT_LEN 50

void line_length_visualization(size_t maxlength) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < maxlength; i++) {
        printf("=");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

unsigned int count_big_words(char *str, int max_line_length) {
    unsigned int word_length = 0;        // Length of the word
    unsigned int big_words = 0;          // Number of big words
    // Iterate over the original string to check how many line breaks "\n" will be inserted and for long words 
    size_t str_len = strlen(str);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str_len + 1; i++) {
        // Increase word_length if it don't find a space
        if (str[i] != ' ') {
            word_length++;
        } 
        else {
            // If a word_length is bigger than the limit, increase the number of big_words
            if (word_length > max_line_length) {
                big_words++;
            }
            // Reset the word length
            word_length = 0;
        }
    }
    // Check the last word
    if (word_length > max_line_length) {
        big_words++;
    }

    return big_words;
}

bool is_a_big_word(char *str, int max_line_length, int last_space_position) {
    unsigned int word_length = 0;         // Size of the analyzed word
    bool inside_ANSI = false;       // Flag to determine if it is within an ANSI character
    // Iterate over the string from the initial position (where it has the last space) until it finds another space or "\0"
    int i = last_space_position + 1;
    while ((str[i] != ' ') && (str[i] != '\0')){
        // Check if it is inside an ANSI escape character
        if (str[i] == '\x1b') {
            inside_ANSI = true;
        }
        // If it is a normal character, increase word length
        if (inside_ANSI == false) {
            word_length++;
        }
        if (inside_ANSI == true && str[i] == 'm') {
            inside_ANSI = false;
        }
        // Advance one position in the string
        i++;
    }
    // Determine if it is a big word or not
    if (word_length >= max_line_length) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

void get_last_space_pos_and_length(char *str, size_t i, bool *inside_ANSI, int *last_space_position, int *length_counter) {
    /* This function updates the last space position of the string and the length counter to control the line breaks */
    // Check if position is a ANSI escape character
    if (str[i] == '\x1b') {
        (*inside_ANSI) = true;
    }
    // If in position of normal string
    if ((*inside_ANSI) == false) {
        // Check if it is space
        if (str[i] == ' ') {
            // If is a space, hold as last space position
            (*last_space_position) = i;
        }
        // Increase the length counter
        (*length_counter)++;
    }
    // If position is inside a ANSI escape sequense and is in the last position of the sequence flag
    // inside_ANSI as false (this instruction must come after all checks for inside_ANSI variable)
    if ((*inside_ANSI) == true && str[i] == 'm') {
        (*inside_ANSI) = false;
    }   
}

char *split_string_with_small_words(char *str, int max_line_length) {
    // Get the size of the original string
    size_t str_len = strlen(str);
    // Make a duplicate of the string
    char *new_str = strdup(str);  // Size of the string + potential
    int last_space_position = 0;    // Monitor of the last space position
    int length_counter = 0;         // Counter to check max line length
    bool inside_ANSI = false;
    // Iterate over the original string to check how many line breaks "\n" will be inserted            
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str_len + 1; i++) {
        get_last_space_pos_and_length(str, i, &inside_ANSI, &last_space_position, &length_counter);
        // Check if length_counter reaches the limit of max_line_length and if it founds any space
        if (length_counter == max_line_length + 1 && last_space_position != 0) {
            // If reaches max_line_length, substitute the last space position with a new line char
            new_str[last_space_position] = '\n';
            // Reset monitor of the length counter to the position of the word after the space
            length_counter = i - last_space_position;
        }
    }

    return new_str;
}

char *my_split_string(char *str, int max_line_length) {
    bool inside_big_word = false;   // Flag to determine if it is within a big word 
    bool moved_right = false;       // Flag to determine if it moved the memory to the right 
    int add_right = 0;
    // Check if there is any big words
    unsigned int big_words = count_big_words(str, max_line_length);    
    // Check if there is a big word
    if (big_words == 0) {
        char *new_str = split_string_with_small_words(str, max_line_length);
        return new_str;       
    } else {
        // If there is any big words, allocate memory accordingly
        size_t str_len = strlen(str);
        size_t new_str_len = str_len + 1 + (str_len/max_line_length); // Length of the string + space for \0 + additional space for line breaks of big words
        char *new_str = malloc(new_str_len);  
        // Declare some variables 
        int last_space_position = 0;    // Monitor of the last space position
        int length_counter = 0;         // Counter to check max line length
        bool inside_ANSI = false;       // Flag to determine if it is within an ANSI character
        size_t j = 0; 
        // Iterate over the string
        for (size_t i = 0; i < str_len; i++) {
            get_last_space_pos_and_length(str, i, &inside_ANSI, &last_space_position, &length_counter);
            // If reaches the length limit
            if (length_counter == max_line_length + 1) {
                // Check if it is a big word
                bool big_word = is_a_big_word(str, max_line_length, last_space_position);
                if (big_word == true) {
                    // Put a newline character at the end of the line
                    new_str[j] = '\n';
                    // Define last space position as the end of the big word and advance one character
                    last_space_position = j;
                    j++;
                    // Reset the monitor of the length
                    length_counter = 0;

                } else {
                    // Put a newline character in the last space character added by the number of additional newlines for big words
                    new_str[last_space_position + (j - i)] = '\n';
                    length_counter = i - last_space_position;
                } 

            } 
            // Copy str character to new_str
            new_str[j] = str[i];
            j++;
            
        }
        return new_str;
    } 
}

int main(void) {
    
    char *str_1 = "\x1b[33m=>\x1b[32m This is a very very loong message that needs to be inserted into this program to test the split function. Lets make this string really big to test it properly.\x1b[0m\n";
    char *str_2 = "\x1b[33m=>\x1b[32m File \x1b[35m'luaguedesc/data/in/DRDs/very_long_input_file.txt' (25 bytes)\x1b[32m successfully loaded! I haveeee also another input file to be loaded \x1b[35m'luaguedesc/data/DRDs/input_files/very_long_input_file_2.txt' (27 bytes)\x1b[32m that was successfully loaded! AndAFinalVeryVeryBigWordWithManyCharactersAndNoSpaces.\x1b[0m\n";
    char *str_3 = "\x1b[33m=>\x1b[32m dhaisdhiasudhuasihdiusahdiusahdhasiudsiuhdsauihdsuihdsaiuhdsaihudsaiuhdsauihsaduhiasdhuadsiuhdasihudiuasduhisaiuhdasuihdasuihuidasiuhuhiadsiuhasduihdaiudas.\x1b[0m\n";
    
    line_length_visualization(MAX_PRINT_LEN);
    char *new_str_1 = my_split_string(str_1, MAX_PRINT_LEN);
    printf("%s", new_str_1);
    
    line_length_visualization(MAX_PRINT_LEN);
    char *new_str_2 = my_split_string(str_2, MAX_PRINT_LEN);
    printf("%s", new_str_2);
    
    
    line_length_visualization(MAX_PRINT_LEN);
    char *new_str_3 = my_split_string(str_3, MAX_PRINT_LEN);
    printf("%s", new_str_3);
    
    free(new_str_1);
    free(new_str_2);
    free(new_str_3);
}
```

The function `line_length_visualization(...)` serves as a template to check if the text is being wrapped at the right location

`count_big_words(...)` determines if there is a word that is bigger than the line length limit

`is_a_big_word(...)` determines if the next word is bigger than the line length limit

`get_last_space_pos_and_length(...)` determines where the last space occurred in text, and also accounts for the monitoring of the maximum length and handles ANSI characters

`split_string_with_small_words(...)` is a function that wraps a text with small words. This function is working properly.

`my_split_string(...)` should be the general function that wraps both texts with small words and with big words larger than the line length limit.

There are three strings that I'm using for tests: The first is a string with small words, the second is a general string with small and big words, and the third is a string with an arrow followed by a single big word.

The output of the code is the following:

First string:

```
==================================================
=> This is a very very loong message that needs to
be inserted into this program to test the split
function. Lets make this string really big to test
it properly.
```

Second string:

```
==================================================
=> File 'luaguedesc/data/in/DRDs/very_long_input_f
ile.txt' (25 bytes) successfully loaded! I haveeee
also another input file to be loaded 'luaguedesc/d
ata/DRDs/input_files/very_long_input_file_2.txt'
(27 bytes) that was successfully loaded! AndAFinal
VeryVeryBigWordWithManyCharactersAndNoSpaces.
```

Third string:

```
==================================================
=> dhaisdhiasudhuasihdiusahdiusahdhasiudsiuhdsauih
dsuihdsaiuhdsaihudsaiuhdsauihsaduhiasdhuadsiuhdasih
udiuasduhisaiuhdasuihdasuihuidasiuhuhiadsiuhasduihd
aiudas.
```

The second output looks fine, but if I made a slight change by adding some character after the word "haveeee", as haveeeeE, it doesnt wrap correctly:

```
==================================================
=> File 'luaguedesc/data/in/DRDs/very_long_input_f
ile.txt' (25 bytes) successfully loaded! I haveeeeE also another input file to be loaded 'luaguedesc/d
ata/DRDs/input_files/very_long_input_file_2.txt'
(27 bytes) that was successfully loaded! AndAFinal
VeryVeryBigWordWithManyCharactersAndNoSpaces.
```

The third string is also problematic. It is wrapping the text one character after it should in the second and third lines.

I tried many things but cannot find a solution to that. Could someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read this: http://eprg.org/G53DOC/pdfs/knuth-plass-breaking.pdf

Comment: Offering https://stackoverflow.com/a/78032012/17592432 as an example of evolving from a "simple" scheme in gradual steps of increasing capability (and specificity.) Write less code, and avoid re-scanning the same series of characters. It should be an almost trivial extension of this example to detect, and even to _break_, long words into the next output line (or across 2 or more output lines). Detecting & suppressing ANSI escape sequences can be easily achieved, too... KISS...

Comment: Off topic: In `my_split_string` the `else` isn't needed.  Having the `else` is not a bug but to me it's a bit confusing...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a description of some problems (but I don't think it covers all problems).

`count_big_words` completely ignore the escape codes, i.e. the escape codes are being counted as part of the words. So the returned value may be wrong.

`is_a_big_word` have the line `int i = last_space_position + 1;` to set the starting point for the iteration. When you call `is_a_big_word` the first time on a string, `last_space_position` is zero so the iteration starts from index one. In other words, the first character is not handled correctly - it's ignored. So for instance, if the first character is the escape, your code doesn't detect that you are parsing an escape sequence.

In general your code looks for spaces inside the string but it never looks for newlines (`\n`). So for instance a trailing newline will be counted as part of a word.

And this also looks strange:

```
unsigned int count_big_words(char *str, int max_line_length) {
    unsigned int word_length = 0;        // Length of the word
    unsigned int big_words = 0;          // Number of big words
    // Iterate over the original string to check how many line breaks "\n" will be inserted and for long words 
    size_t str_len = strlen(str);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str_len + 1; i++) {
                                  ^^^^
                                   ???
```

Why add one to `str_len`? It makes the code count the nul-termination character as part of a word. For a string like `"1234567\n";` the function `count_big_words` will end up with `word_length` being 9. That's obviously wrong as the word is just 7 characters. So if `MAX_PRINT_LEN` is set to 8, your function will count a "big word" even if there isn't any "big word" in the string.